# Запись объекта в файл. Правильное закрытие потоков

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Делаю так:

```
    try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("path"))) {
        oos.writeObject(myObject);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
```

Использую конструкцию try-with-resources, которая как бы автоматически вызывает метод close();

Вопрос0: Можно ли так делать или лучше обычный блок try, в котором писать flush() и close() или ещё как вариант писать close() в блоке finally()?

Вопрос1: Если инициализировать потоки отдельно, как правильно закрывать их по отдельности?

Вопрос2: Для десериализации объекта такая конструкция (try-with-resources) тоже допустима?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) так делать можно. Для этого try с ресурсами и создавался, чтобы писать меньше.

2) если вы про пример кода из вопроса, то это у вас всё равно один поток. А если вы действительно хотите открыть несколько потоков, то можно это делать через символ ; в скобках try. Система сама их закроет настолько насколько это возможно.

3) уточните что именно вы хотите сделать. Я доотвечу.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Уточню. Если я разделю один поток на два, то есть создам отдельно сначала поток FileOutputStream, а потом ObjectOutputStream и передам ему объект FileOutputStream, я все равно могу писать их через ; в скобках try?

Comment: Можете привести пример как вы это представляете? И зачем именно так?

Comment: Спасибо за содействие. Я уже разобрался. Использую такии конструкции для сериалилаци/десереализации объектов.